# SQL Server 2005 - cross apply, tvf, and update/delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

How can I make something like this

```
select 
    a.atest, a.btest, a.ctest, b.atest, b.btest
from 
    test.dbo.rm a(nolock)
cross apply 
    wat.dbo.ar(a.atest,a.btest) b
where 
    a.rmd = 9 and a.btest > 0

alter function ar(@atest varchar(25), @btest numeric(19,5)) 
returns table as 
    return
    (
        select atest, btest from test.dbo.rm (nolock)
        where rmd = 1 and atest=@atest and btest=@btest
    )
```

with delete statement or update. I don't want to make duplicates so after I choose one `b.atest` I want to delete the record with `b.atest` or set `b.btest` to 0. This query is working on table that contain about 5-10 million of records.. so it must be quick.

Answer (score 2):

Use query without function:

```
select a.atest,a.btest,a.ctest,b.atest,b.btest
from test.dbo.rm a(nolock)
cross apply (
        select top 1 atest, btest 
        from test.dbo.rm t (nolock)
        where t.rmd = 1 and t.atest=a.atest and t.btest=a.btest
        )b
where a.rmd = 9 and a.btest > 0
```

You can also use Left join instead of cross apply:

```
select *
from (
    select a.atest,a.btest,a.ctest,b.atest,b.btest,
          row_number() over ( partition by b.atest, b.btest order by b.id) as row
    from test.dbo.rm a(nolock)
    LEFT JOIN test.dbo.rm b ON b.rmd = 1 and b.atest=a.atest and b.btest=a.btest
    where a.rmd = 9 and a.btest > 0
)z
where z.row = 1
```

Comment: Thanks ;) but it don't solves the problem with duplicates.. :/ the b.atest can be pick more than once and I dont want this type of situation.. got any idea how to fix this? btest it's a amount and atest it's document name.